# TweetViewFetchAdapter.setTweetIds does not work in android

Tags: android, twitter

I want to display some tweets with the twitter API in my app. To do so I have fetched some tweet ids (which is working without any hassle) and use the TweetViewFetchAdapter adapter provided by the Twitter API to display my tweets. 
The weird thing is: this has worked at some point! But then suddenly it stopped working (company app, multiple people working on the code but I haven't seen any changes to the twitter stuff in the time between working and not working)

The code is super straight forward taken from the official twitter site:

```
// fill the tweet adapter with the loaded tweet ids
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(List<Long> params){
                if (params != null && params.size() > 0) {
                    adapter.setTweetIds(params,
                            new LoadCallback<List<Tweet>>() {
                                @Override
                                public void success(List<Tweet> tweets) {
                                    Log.i("twitter", "Success!");
                                }
                                @Override
                                public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
                                    Log.e("twitter", "Exception: " + exception.getMessage());
                                }
                            });
                }
                Log.i("twitter", "params.size = " + params.size() + "adapter.tweetCount = " + adapter.getCount());
            }
```

(inside an AsyncTask). The adapter seems to fail to set the tweet ids as the debug output is **I/twitter﹕ params.size = 10 adapter.tweet Count = 0**
I tried to debug/have a log output in the success/failure callbacks, but I never got anything as if the methods would never be called (quite weird actually..)

Regarding log cat output I haven't seen any, but I'm afraid there is a little chance I might have messed it up as we just recently moved to Android Studio and I just can't get my head around some stuff there yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was caused by an wrong version of okhttp / okhttp-urlconnection.

The weird part is that no debug messages was shown. This code resolved the debug message issue and helped resolve the issue overall:

```
final Fabric fabric = new Fabric.Builder(this)
            .kits(new Twitter(authConfig))
            .logger(new DefaultLogger(Log.DEBUG))
            .debuggable(true)
            .build();
Fabric.with(fabric);
```

Overall fix: change build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
// ...
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.3.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.3.0'
}
```

Original conversation: https://twittercommunity.com/t/adapter-settweetid-seems-to-be-unable-to-load-the-tweets-but-doesnt-fire-a-success-failure-callback/36506/13